# Can't bundle gems with capistrano and rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano, bundler

I use `capistrano` to deploy rails app. I have set up `rbenv` and using `capistrano-rbenv` in my `deploy.rb`file

Error message when deploying:

```
Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources
 Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

On server when I run `bundle install` I get `Could not locate Gemfile`

`$ gem env` returns

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/deployer/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm that rake 10.1 is on the server through `ssh` login.  It is a dependency to your process.

Rake is a gem like any other, so on the server run

```
gem install rake -v=10.1.0
```

if `gem which` returns nothing, then you need to first install rubygems, e.g.

```
apt-get install rubygems
```

Ensure that apt-get properly configures your `PATH`.  You may need to re-source your `.bash_profile` (or whichever for your shell — or login again to get a new shell

---

I will update this answer if more details emerge.

Comment: How do I install? Through apt-get install?

Comment: rake installed, I installed rubygems as well with `apt-get install rubygems`, but `gem which` returns nothing and `cap deploy` fails with  `Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources`

Comment: @olivier then you `$PATH` is broken.  I bet when you run `gem install` it barks that 'gem does not exist'.  Consider that `cap` or any of the other programs involved may know explicit paths to certain packages / utils, and therefore not rely upon `PATH` to know how to find things.  See my updated' answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the `capistrano-rbenv`gem and it finally worked out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are requiring `capistrano/bundler` in your `Capfile`, be sure to specify the gemfile location in your `deploy.rb`:

```
# setup bundler
set :bundle_gemfile, -> { release_path.join('Gemfile') }
```

See: https://github.com/capistrano/bundler